# Convert to binary for VHDL compiler

Tags: binary, vhdl

I have a lot of data points that need to be converted to binary format. 
For example:

```
if clk_cntr = (STAR +3400) then  --6.8us

    DAC <= "01110100011111";   --7455  2.8v

end if;
```

DAC is a std_logic_vector and must be in binary mode from my understanding.

I have a stack of these if-thens. Currently, I have to "look up" the value and convert to binary. I am new to VHDL and I am looking for a way to allow the compiler to convert my std_logic_vector DAC value from readable to binary. Something like...

```
if clk_cntr = (STAR +3400) then  --6.8us

    DAC <= binary(14)[7455];   --7455  2.8v

end if;
```

I have looked in all of the incorrect places on the web and in a few books I have but have not been successful. 
How do I get the compiler to convert to 14 bit binary for VHDL to understand?

Comment: Show declarations. std_logic_vector isn't a binary number while type signed or unsigned are. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values and Annex G, G.4.8.3 Conversion functions. Something along the lines of `DAC <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(7455,14));` where 7455 is a decimal literal of a natural and the number of elements is 14. If DAC is type std_logic_vector an unsigned value can be explicitly converted from type unsigned (9.3.6 Type conversions), they're closely related.

Comment: Or use numeric_std_unsigned and convert direct to SLV: DAC <= to_slv(7455, DAC'length);

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, I only need to get my TDS-3012 o-scope to output to something other than diskettes. I am using a digital analog converter  to make a waveform